# Inverse and composite functions

Tags: functions, inverse

If $f(x)=\frac{x}{1-√x}$, $x≥0$ and $g(x)=3x+1, $
Solve the equation $(f^{-1}\circ g)(x)=9/16$.
Hint:do not attempt to find $f^{-1}(x)$.

Comment: Thanks for the question hint! What have you tried?

Comment: Just to be sure : is it a multiplication (not a composition) between $f^{-1}$ and $g$?

Comment: do you meant $$f^{-1}(g(x))=\frac{9}{16}$$

Comment: Unfortunately it is not a multiplication but a composition of f^-1(x) and g(x).

Comment: but $f^{-1}(x)$ doesn't exist

Comment: @Serene : You should say "fortunatly" : the problem is far more harder with multiplication instead of composition ;)

Comment: $f^{-1}\circ g$

Comment: Thank you. I solved it thanks to Mr David Quinn who suggested equating g(x) to f(9/16). Yes indeed the problem was much easier with composition than if it were a multiplication.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just have to solve $g(x)=f(\frac{9}{16})$